# cannot install JDK 8 on wine Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java-8, wine

Hi I cannot install JDK 8 on Wine Ubuntu, it gives me an error message with no explanation. I tried to follow the following instructions but it also doesn't work... https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31528&iTestingId=90897

Anibody can help?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to do that instead of installing the standard Linux JDK?

Comment: This is a good question.. the fact is that I'm using a broker provided trading software that is running over JAVA 8, incredibly it works with java for OSX, Windows but not for Linux!! So the only solution I see is to use wine in order to run windows version of java8 on linux

Comment: @DiegoDiTommaso have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Not really, I did not find a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we use the same broker (Directa?), and had the same issue.

This is how i made **Oracle Java 8** work on **Wine** on **Xubuntu 16.10** and also able to run **JNLP** (Java Web Start) applications from **Firefox for Windows**, I hope following these passages will solve your problem too.

I used PlayOnLinux, the Wine graphical front-end, but probably this will work also straight on Wine paths; maybe you can try using PlayOnLinux if working on Wine wasn't successfull.

- if you haven't done already, install PlayOnLinux from Ubuntu "Software" package manager;
- from PlayOnLinux, click on "Install a program" and search for "Firefox" then press Install: a wizard will guide you to the proper installation of Firefox (it will offer you to download the Firefox Windows installer, or you can point to a previuosly downloaded one);
- download from java.com the latest version of the JDK **(not JRE!)** for Windows, [current link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). I choosed the Windows x86 version (I am on a 32bit machine), filename `jdk-8u121-windows-i586.exe` for JDK version 8.121;
- this part of the procedure is taken from the WineHQ [page](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31528&iTestingId=90897) you mentioned: move the JDK installation package on the C: emulated path that PlayOnLinux created for Firefox:

  ```
  /home/[linux username]/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/MozillaFirefox/drive_c/
  ```
- navigate to that path and execute from the shell:

  ```
  $ 7z x jdk-8u121-windows-i586.exe
  ```

  (of course change the file name in case of different JDK version): this will create a `tools.zip` file in the same path;
- create a `jdk` subfolder and navigate into it, then unzip the `tools.zip` file:

  ```
  $ mkdir jdk
  $ cd jdk
  $ unzip ../tools.zip
  ```
- for the next step, you have to run `unpack200`: you can get this JAR unpacker from another Oracle JDK or JRE linux installation (you find it in `bin` folder); if you don't have one available, you can install the Oracle JDK for linux on your machine so you will have the `unpack200` executable ready to use, for this you can follow [this procedure](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html);
- execute these shell commands to unpack the JDK JARs:

  ```
  $ find -type f | grep '\.pack$' | while read __line; do \
  __outjar="$(dirname "$__line")/$(basename "$__line" .pack).jar"
  echo "$__line" -- "$__outjar"; \
  unpack200 "$__line" "$__outjar"; \
  done
  ```
- Now the Oracle JDK is ready to use, test if it's working under Wine with this shell command:
  `wine bin/java -version`
  it should answer with the Java version and Runtime Environment statements; normal Java applications can then be run using the executables under the `/jdk/bin` path;
- in order to be able to execute the JNLP files, all you have to do is to download the desired JNLP in Firefox for Windows and choose "Open with..." then point to the Java Web Start executable, that is located in the C: emulated path under jdk/bin/javaws.exe.

  Its complete path would then be:

  ```
  /home/[linux username]/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/MozillaFirefox/drive_c/jdk/bin/javaws.exe
  ```

  In this way all JNLP files open in the browser will be open with the JWS machine.

This is enough to install Oracle Java 8 under Wine and run the Java/JNLP applications just fine.

I had a second issue with the firewall in order to get the price stream working on the broker application, but this is not in the topic of this answer.

I hope this helps. If you find any problem in any of these steps let me know.

Comment: Directa, you're right! Thanks for the guide!                                               Actually I renounced using the Darwin GUI and switched directly to the Darwin Command Line that works just fine.  I'm developing algotrading strategies, if you're interested maybe we can collaborate. This is my e-mail diego.ditommaso@gmail.com